# Comparing multiple file items using re

Tags: python, regex, file-io

Currently I have a script that finds all the lines across multiple input files that have something in the format of 
`Matches: 500 (54.3 %)` and prints out the top 10 highest matches in percentage.

I want to be able to have it *also* output the top 10 lines for score ex: Score: 4000

```
import re

def get_values_from_file(filename):
    f = open(filename)
    winpat = re.compile("([\d\.]+)\%")
    xinpat = re.compile("[\d]") #ISSUE, is this the right regex for it? Score: 500****

    values = []
    scores = []

    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.find("Matches") >=0:
        percn = float(winpat.findall(line)[0])
        values.append(percn)

    elif line.find("Score") >=0:
        hey = float(xinpat.findall(line)[0])
        scores.append(hey)
    return (scores,values)


all_values = []    
all_scores = []

for filename in ["out0.txt", "out1.txt"]:#and so on
values = get_values_from_file(filename)
all_values += values
all_scores += scores

all_values.sort()
all_values.reverse()

all_scores.sort()  #also for scores
all_scores.reverse()

print(all_values[0:10])
print(all_scores[0:10])
```

Is my **regex for the score format correct?** I believe that's where I am having the issue, as it doesn't output both correctly.

Any thoughts? Should I split it into two functions?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems that an space character exist between "54.3" and "%" in your example format. To treat that space, first regex pattern should be "winpat = re.compile("([\d\.]+)\s\%")".  (I add space(\s) between number and percentaga)

Comment: Since we don't see the input, can you give a sample output?

Comment: @Fumu7 : I _suspect_ that space is a transcription error, since user3295674 says that the `winpat` stuff works ok. But if we want to handle a _possible_ space, then `'([\d.]+)\s*%'` or `'([\d.]+)\s?%'` would be better.

Comment: @user3295674 Could you please fix the indenting in your code under  `for filename in ["out0.txt", "out1.txt"]:`.

Comment: Also, there's a typo / transcription error. `values = get_values_from_file(filename)` should be `scores, values = get_values_from_file(filename)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my regex for the score format correct?

No, it should be `r"\d+"`.

- You don't need `[]`. Those brackets establish a character class representing all of the characters inside the brackets. Since you only have one character type inside the bracket, they do nothing.
- You only match a single character. You need a `*` or a `+` to match a sequence of characters.
- You have an unescaped backslash in your string. Use the `r` prefix to allow the regular expression engine to see the backslash.

## Commentary:

If it were me, I'd let the regular expression do all of the work, and skip `line.find()` altogether:

```
#UNTESTED
def get_values_from_file(filename):
    winpat = re.compile(r"Matches:\s*\d+\s*\(([\d\.]+)\%\)")
    xinpat = re.compile(r"Score:\s*([\d]+)")

    values = []
    scores = []

    # Note: "with open() as f" automatically closes f
    with open(filename) as f:
        # Note: "for line in f" more memory efficient
        # than "for line in f.readlines()"
        for line in f:
           win = winpat.match(line)
           xin = xinpat.match(line)
           if win: values.append(float(win.group(0)))
           if xin: scores.append(float(xin.group(0)))
    return (scores,values)
```

Just for fun, here is a version of the routine which calls `re.findall` exactly once per file:

```
# TESTED

# Compile this only once to save time
pat = re.compile(r'''
    (?mx)                                  # multi-line, verbose
    (?:Matches:\s*\d+\s*\(([\d\.]+)\s*%\)) # "Matches: 300 (43.2%)"
    |
    (?:Score:\s*(\d+))                     # "Score: 4000"
''')
def get_values_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        values, scores = zip(*pat.findall(f.read()))
    values = [float(value) for value in values if value]
    scores = [float(score) for score in scores if score]
    return scores, values
```

Comment: +1 This is what I was thinking too. Because he only grabs the firs t result from findall.

Comment: Of course, if I were *really* cool, I'd combine the two regular expressions so there was only one call to `.match()` per input line.

Comment: As for using `match()` (or `search()`) instead of `findall(), I agree. But I dunno about combining the regexes. I reckon regex stuff should be kept as simple as possible (but no simpler :) ). And combining the regexes would make the rest of the code slightly more complicated. But it would be interesting to compare the speeds of the two approaches...

Comment: Ok, Rob. Your new version is pretty neat.

Answer (score 1):

No. `xinpat` will only match single digits, so `findall()` will return a list of single digits, which is a bit messy.  Change it to

`xinpat = re.compile("[\d]+")`

Actually, you don't need the square brackets here, so you could simplify it to

`xinpat = re.compile("\d+")`

BTW, the names `winpat` and `xinpat` are a bit opaque. The `pat` bit is ok, but `win` & `xin`? And `hey` isn't great either. But I guess `xin` and `hey` are just temporary names you made up when you decidd to expand the program.

---

Another thing I just noticed, you don't need to do

```
all_values.sort()
all_values.reverse()
```

You can (and should) do that in one hit:

```
all_values.sort(reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, they are test variables for now, but very good point. I changed the regex and that one works, but for some reason when I do print(all_scores[0:10]) and the same for all_values, it doesn't output the top 10 values, but all of them. Why is this? It was working when it was only printing out one (values).

Comment: That's odd. I haven't tried to run your code due to lack of input data. But if you supply us a little sample input data I'll be happy to to debug it for you.

Comment: thank you for your willingness to help. I ended up fixing it, your solution was of great help!